# how to add links like delete and update manually using table class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i was successful in creating table using codeigniter table class but don't know how to add values manually like links and i was successful in showing all the values from backend to my table but dont know how to restrict particular value view and how to add links like delete upate to my table
code 1:this is my controller function which opens when i click view users link in my admin panel

```
    public function viewusers()
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_model');
         $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();


            // print_r($aaa); die();
            //  $data['aa'] = "sd"; 

            //$data['books'] = $this->abc();
            $data['books'] = $this->insert_model->pagination();
             //print "<pre>";print_r($data);die();
             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view_admin');
             $this->load->view('admin_view', $data);

    }
```

code2: this is my model(insertmodel)in which there is pagination function in which i am using page class of codeigniter to create table

```
    public function pagination(){

        //$this->load->model('insert_model');
         //$data ['query'] = $this->insert_model->view_data(); 
        $this->load->library('table');

        // Load Pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $total_row = $this->db->count_all("register");
        // Config setup
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/welcome/viewusers';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $kk=$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $rpp =$config['per_page'] =15;
        $nop=ceil($total_row/$rpp);
        // I added this extra one to control the number of links to show up at each page.
         $config['num_links'] = $nop;


        // Initialize
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // Query the database and get results
        // Here we add the limit and the offset
        // The second parameter is the limit, since we are showing
        // 10 per page, the limit should be 10

        if($this->uri->segment(3)){
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
            }
            else{
            $page = 1;
            }
        $offset = ($rpp*$page)-$rpp;
        $qry = $this->db->get('register',15, $offset);

        // Create custom headers
       $header = array('id','username','lastname','email' , 'password', 'image','status','operations');
        $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="mytable">' );
       // foreach($qry as $rows)
       /* {
            $links  = anchor('controller/edit/'.$row->id ,'Edit');
        }*/

$this->table->set_template($tmpl);

 /*$this->table->add_row(
        $row->id,
        $row->fname,
        $row->lname,
        $row->email,
        $row->pass,
        $row->image,
           //add the links you created to the last row, corresponding to your 'Links' Header
    );*/
         //Set the headings
        $this->table->set_heading($header);
        // Load the view and send the results
       // print_r($offset);die();
     /*   if($offset == 0)
        {   

        return $data['books'];

        }
        else
        {
       //$data['books'] = $this->abc();
            $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();
        $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
         $this->load->view('navside_view');
           $this->load->view('admin_view', $data);
            }
       // print_r($data); die();

    }*/return $qry->result_array();

}}
```

code3:this is my admin view in which i am showing fetched data from database in table which is generated by using table class of codeigniter and i dont know how to add manually links like delete or update in this table and also  how to show restricted values from database in table but firstly solve the problem of showing links like delete update to table columns...

```
 <?php


 if(isset($books)){
  echo $this->table->generate($books); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); }?>
```

Comment: Have you tried this:https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Comment: yes but m confused as m new to codeigniter , and i dont understand how to just print link inside my update column and delete column and in other columns values are coming from database but i only want that there should some thing so that i can add links to tables. can u help me

Comment: You can use `add_row` function to do that.

Comment: plz can u read my code and can do changes in it or give me sample example

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thing in my controller might be you get some hint from it.

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('table');
    $data_rows = $this->my_model->get();
    $tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table id="sample_1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="sample_1_info">');
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
    $this->table->set_heading('Name', 'Type','Reason', 'Status', 'Approval');
    foreach ($data_rows as $row) {
        $approvals = anchor('my_url' . $row->id, 'Approve', array('class' => 'btn green mini')) . " ";
        $approvals .= anchor('my_url' . $row->id, 'Refuse', array('class' => 'btn red mini'));

        //I have added all the columns with two extra columns named approvals links in it.
        $content = array($row->name, $row->type, $row->reason, $status, $approvals);
        $this->table->add_row($content);
    }
    $leaves_table = $this->table->generate();
    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('leaves/lists', array('leaves_table' => $leaves_table));
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}
```